# Plot of training and validation loss looks weird

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch

I plot training and validation loss similar to what is mentioned here [plot training and validation loss in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74754493/plot-training-and-validation-loss-in-pytorch) as shown below. However, I got the below curve.

The issue I was expecting both the training and validation loss to start almost from the same value and to go down together, but the validation loss starts far below. Is there something wrong with my code or is this normal?

[image]

```
# create a function (this my favorite choice)
def RMSELoss(predicted,target):
    return torch.sqrt(torch.mean((predicted-target)**2))

criterion = RMSELoss

# loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(x, y))
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
epochs = 50    
n_total_steps = len(train_dataset)

trainingEpoch_loss = []
validationEpoch_loss = []

for epoch in range(epochs):
    step_loss = []
    model.train()
    for i, data in enumerate(train_dataset):
        feature,target = data['data'].type(torch.FloatTensor),torch.tensor(data['target']).type(torch.FloatTensor)
         
        # Clear the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Forward Pass
        outputs = model(feature)
        # Find the Loss
        training_loss = criterion(outputs, target)
        # Calculate gradients
        training_loss.backward()
        # Update Weights
        optimizer.step()
        # Calculate Loss
        step_loss.append(training_loss.item())
        if (i+1) % 1 == 0:
            print (f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{epochs}], Step [{i+1}/{n_total_steps}], Loss: {training_loss.item():.4f}')
    trainingEpoch_loss.append(np.array(step_loss).mean())
 
    model.eval()     # Optional when not using Model Specific layer
    for i, data in enumerate(val_dataset):
        validationStep_loss = []
        feature,target = data['data'].type(torch.FloatTensor),torch.tensor(data['target']).type(torch.FloatTensor)
        
        # Forward Pass
        outputs = model(feature)
        # Find the Loss
        validation_loss = criterion(outputs, target)
        # Calculate Loss
        validationStep_loss.append(validation_loss.item())
    validationEpoch_loss.append(np.array(validationStep_loss).mean())


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(trainingEpoch_loss, label='train_loss')
plt.plot(validationEpoch_loss,label='val_loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show
```